# How to create IsSelected property for custom itemscontrolItem?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, wpf-controls, custom-controls

I am trying to create a custom ItemsControl by directly inheriting from ItemsControl (WPF/Silverlight, I am using same code base for both). I have created an Item class for it by inheriting from ContentControl. I want to create IsSelected property for the Item class. I reflected the ListBoxItem class but am not very clear how IsSelected property is getting set.
Any suggestions/ pointers will be really helpful.

Comment: Why are you choosing to extend `ItemsControl`, rather than `Selector` or `ListBox`, which already implement a selection behavior?

Comment: I agree with Daniel.  I have not yet found a reason to create a custom implementation of ItemsControl.  What is the hoped for extended functionality, as it may be simple enough to change the way the control works through templating or some other way.

Comment: Probably in this way: Set SelectedItem (ItemsControl) -> inside the setter find a control-container -> Set IsSelected. In reverse way you can use PropertyChanged event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an `ItemsControl` with no `ListBox` features except that it internally supports the concept of selection, you can easily create a lookless `ListBox` that is indistinguishable from an `ItemsControl`.  Here are the two two side by side and you can't tell the difference.  The only difference is that the left list supports selection internally.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <x:Array Type="sys:String" x:Key="sampleData">
            <sys:String>Red</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Green</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Blue</sys:String>
        </x:Array>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <UniformGrid Columns="2">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource sampleData}"/>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource sampleData}">
            <ListBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ListBox">
                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                                <ItemsPresenter/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.Style>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <ContentPresenter/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
    </UniformGrid>
</Grid>
```

So the best advice is if you want selection, derive from `ListBox` and style away what you don't want about it or at least derive from `Selector`.